# How to control access permission with git

Tags: permissions, git

I'm using a rental server from hostingrails.com ,
I operate Rails in FastCGI here, by the permissions that SuExec used, which were 755 it seems not to have been able to set permission.(For example, I can't  use with 775)

I used git for development.
I set it to 775 and cannot use the thing which I checked out of from git with the server to commit it with 755 in my PC(MacOSX)
Could you Help me?

Comment: question makes no sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `chmod 755 file`, then a `git add file`, and finally a `git commit file`.  The permissions should be correct the next time you fetch the code.

Comment: Thanks, I had done it . but permission is 775..
git clone git://foo/bar.git